# Convertir un objeto a float o int, python

Tags: python

> Buenas estoy teniendo un problema y es que estoy consumiendo api y la
> api me trae un objeto y en ese objeto hay un numero asi 0.00000876 en
> forma de objeto, y yo lo intento convertir a float con float(numero)
> pero resulta que me lo pone ahora el numero asi 0.000009 como si lo
> redondea y yo no quiero que lo redonde sino que me muestre exactamente
> el numero que me dió la api, como puedo solucionar esto? edite el código simulando lo que sucede miren como me pone 0.000009

```
    import pandas as pd

class Person:
    numero1 = "0.00000876"

ver = Person().numero1

array = [ver]

df = pd.DataFrame(array)

df.loc[0] = df.loc[0].astype(float)

print(df)
```

Comment: Si saben resolverlo de otra manera que se pueda convertir el objeto a float, podrian hacerlo de esa manera porfavor, no tiene que ser exactamente con pandas

Comment: Este código si muestra el problema.

Comment: Si incluso intenté convertir ese dato en string para ver si podia de string ahi si pasarlo a float pero el problema perciste y antes muestra un numero de notacion cientifica todo raro que me deja peor

Comment: Estás confundiendo el "verdadero" valor del dato con cómo se muestra al hacer `print()`. Por defecto `print()` redondea para mostrar el mínimo número de decimales, pero internamente el dato puede tener muchos más. Para variar la cantidad de decimales que print te muestra debes usar cadenas de formato. Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que cantidades que en forma de cadena tienen pocos decimales (por ejemplo 0.2) en su representación interna tienen muchos más decimales y un error (si pides mostrar 54 decimales, en vez de 0.2 verás 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125)

Comment: Para representar de forma **exacta** un número con decimales el formato `float()` no es adecuado y habría que usar en cambio el tipo `Decimal()`. Pero ese complica mucho las operaciones. Probablemente para tu uso el tipo float sea adecuado, junto con el uso apropiado de cadenas de formato para seleccionar cuántos decimales quieres ver

Answer (score 1):

Realmente puedes hacer como lo mencionas

> float(numero)

Ejemplo

```
numero1 = "0.00000876"
num = float(numero1)
```

Si lo imprimes quedaría de la siguiente forma: 8.76e-06, pero para mostrarlo de la forma que tu quieres, tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
print("{:.10f}".format(num))
```

Dentro de las comillas se puede modificar cuantos números quieres mostrar después del punto decimal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos